# Curl of Coulomb field

Tags: electrostatics, coulombs-law

For divergence of Coulomb field, we can directly apply the formula of divergence in spherical coordinate to show that
$$\nabla\cdot\left(\frac{\hat{\mathbf{r}}}{r^2}\right)=0$$
However, the formula doesn't work for $r=0$. But we can consider a small volume enclosing the origin and show that the divergence is infinite at the origin, and that in fact it is a Dirac delta function.

What about curl?

We can similarly apply the formula of curl in spherical coordinate to show that
$$\nabla\times\left(\frac{\hat{\mathbf{r}}}{r^2}\right)=0$$
at all $r\ne 0$.

But how to show that the curl is zero at the origin as well?

Comment: You get $4\pi  \delta^3(r)$

Answer (score 1):

Curl is a vector.   So, for a coulomb field around a point charge, given
that there is NO preferred direction, one cannot believe a nonzero curl.

One definition of curl is a limit of a line integral, and with
that definition, it can be computed at a point discontinuity (by
enclosing the point with a closed curve, and taking the limit as
the curve is reduced toward zero area).  In particular, concentric
circles around a point charge will converge on zero curl for the
electric field.   Heck, on concentric circles around a point charge,
even the infinitesimal elements of the line integral are all individually
zero.